# Who voices the character "Finger" in The Fifth Element?

Tags: casting, voice-acting, the-fifth-element

In *The Fifth Element*, the main character Korben Dallas talks on the phone with someone named **Finger** - an old military friend who also happens to be Korben's boss at the taxi company.

We never see the character, he only exists as a voice on the phone.

### **Whose voice is it?**

This seems like it should have an easy answer on IMDB - but it doesn't. There's no "Finger" on the cast list.

Google returns a lot of speculation, but no confirmed answers. The most popular theory seems to be Vin Diesel, but the timing is questionable (he became famous much later).

It could very well be someone who isn't famous, or even an actor at all. But it's definitely someone. So... Who?

Comment: I'm not going to waste a week-long bounty, but on my word, I'd grant a 500 point bounty to anyone who can provide a positive correct answer to this question.

Comment: been over a week. upping to 600. on "my word", guaranteed bounty for someone who can actually answer the question

Comment: Definitely NOT Vin Diesel. Try again

Answer (score 65):

## We don't know.

No official sources have talked about this, and with a movie this old, I doubt they ever will. Multiple theories exist around the web.

From [TheGamer](https://www.thegamer.com/secrets-you-didnt-know-about-the-fifth-element/):

> **This would be because Finger was voiced by none other than Vin Diesel.**
>
> Diesel went uncredited for this small role. Though Besson has stated that he does not want to make a sequel, I would be very much in favour of Finger being introduced so we can have Riddick and Korben Dallas kicking butts together on screen.

The IMDB Trivia states:

> **Who plays the voices of Finger, Korben's mother, and Mr. Shadow?**
> No one was credited for these roles, and there's no clear evidence as to who was used. However, some have speculated that it was Jill Mullan, who is credited under Other Crew for "special thanks". Others have suggested that Finger sounds like Bill Nunn or Vin Diesel but neither of these have been confirmed.

In [Answers](https://www.answers.com/Q/Who_plays_the_voice_of_Finger_in_The_Fifth_Element),

> Sounds a lot like Nick Chinlund, who also starred with Bruce Willis in Tears of the Sun.

And this random [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNeBK.jpg) link states it was Glenn Fleshler:

> It's rumored on the 'net that it's Vin Diesel. Not that Vin wouldn't have nailed it, but it's not him.  It's this man: Glenn Fleshler.

There's no conclusive answer to be found, I'm afraid.

Comment: You get an upvote (and a big thanks) for a really comprehensive "non-answer". But I really really want to hold the "accept" for the actual answer.

Comment: @LevenTrek Of course. The answer may be out there, and I simply haven't found it. That being said, a "no one knows" may be the only answer to some questions around here

Comment: For the Riddick + Korben Dallas on screen theory, how would that have been conceived back in 1997? AFAIK Riddick came out in 2004.  I know nothing about Riddick - is "Finger" a character in that series?

Comment: @BruceWayne "Riddick", as in the person who plays Riddick, not the literal character, used so they could explain _why_ they'd be excited to see Vin Diesel without having to explicitly spell it out.

Comment: Most sources agree that Vin Diesel's major break was when Steven Spielberg cast him in Saving Private Ryan (1998). He was a virtual unknown in 1997, and if he really was in The Fifth Element, there's no way he would have kept it secret.

Comment: Vin Diesel seems really unlikely — an actor that young would not get cast without an agent, and an actor that young’s agent would insist that he receive credit.